# Converting string to datetime in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am convert the string to datetime using  `Date.parse` and `new Date()`. For example if the string is  `"2/5/2012"` then

```
  var date=new Date(Date.parse("2/5/2012")); // Sun Feb 5 00:00:00 PST 2012

    var date=new Date(Date.parse("2012/15/3"));  //Sun Mar 3 00:00:00 PST 2013
```

Here my doubt is the string that i am giving takes the below format

```
"2/5/2012"  - "mm/dd/yyyy"
"2012/15/3" - "yyyy/mm/dd"
```

I Want to know what are the format that i can use to define the date in string.

can i define string like this "3/2012/4"

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend to use a library like http://momentjs.com/ instead.

Comment: I always provide dates in the for "2 Mar 2014" because that overcomes the issue of having day or month first in the string. Never have trouble with that when you use this format consistently.

Comment: var date = new Date("3/2012/4".replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/g, "$1/$3/$2")) ?

Comment: No need to use `Date.parse`, you can just use `new Date("2/5/2012")`.

Comment: Common (distinguishable) formats that are accepted by `Date.parse` are `MM/DD/YYYY` and `YYYY/MM/DD`